# I am having an issue with my AndroidManifest.xml file in activity name

Tags: android

I'm learning to write the notification code for the first time in android and seeing errors in AndroidManifest.xml file with the activity names(as they are appearing red, I guess meaning error) hence, can't run the app.

The error is thrown in the

android:names(yes in all three of them) ,they can't , I believe fetch the information they required.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.aptech.androidservice.androidnotificationexaample"
 android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".NotificationActivity"
            android:label="Notification Click Action"
            android:name=".SubNotificationActivity"
            android:label="Sub Notification Click Action">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Could you copy an extract of the error in the log message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing this issue because each activity tag can only have one name. Remember xml format is key-value, of which key is UNIQUE, so you have to write multiple tags, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.aptech.androidservice.androidnotificationexaample"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

    <application
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SubNotificationActivity"
        android:label="Sub Notification Click Action"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".NotificationActivity"
        android:label="Notification Click Action"/>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".NotificationActivity"
            android:label="Notification Click Action"
            android:name=".SubNotificationActivity"
            android:label="Sub Notification Click Action">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

That's not how you define activities in your app, each activity must have a separate activity tag.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".NotificationActivity"
        android:label="Notification Click Action"/>
    <activity android:name=".SubNotificationActivity"
        android:label="Sub Notification Click Action">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```